# Visual Studio 2019 and classic ASP: unable to open script document

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, asp-classic

I need to debug a classic asp application and I'm experiencing a strange behaviour.

This is my setup:

- site name: loc.testsite.com
- web site folder: d:\loc.testsite.com
- entry in hosts: 192.168.1.11 loc.testsite.com
- iis:

  - Enable Client-side debugging: true
  - Enable Server-side debugging: true
  - Send errors to browser: true

Pages:

**default.asp**

```
<!--#include file="include.asp" -->
<%
main

function main()
    stop
    f1()
    
    dim x
    x = 1
end function   
%>
```

**include.asp**

```
<%
    function f1()
        dim a
        a = 1
    end function
%>
```

When I open *loc.testsite.com* in my browser, a request to launch debugger is shown due to *stop* instruction in *default.asp*.
Visual Studio launches and I can see *default.asp* code.
I start debugging with "step into" (F11 in a default environment) and I enter *include.asp*.
I can see *include.asp* code, now I'm in *f1()* so I keep stepping till "*end function*".
Now I should return to *default.asp* at line "*x = 1*", but I see this message instead: "Unable to open script document".
After I press OK the message "Default.asp not found".

I often debug classic asp code and I never faced this issue; this has been happening for about a month.

I tried on two different machines with the same result.

Visual Studio is updated to version 16.7.6.

Comment: Honestly, I've never used VS for debugging Classic ASP. Wouldn't guarantee that VS would support either as Classic ASP / VBScript are fairly ancient at this point.

Comment: @Lankymart what tool you are using for debug ASP Classic? I am also using only VS for debugging purpose, starting from version VS.NET 2002

Comment: @Zam just debug flags in code and `Response.Write` statements along with a custom `debug()` function which will write out information to screen including the contents of arrays as tables. Served me well for years.

Comment: I've been debugging classic asp in every version of VS since 2010. No problems.

Comment: @LarryBud Did you try to step into an included page with 16.7.0+? What happens when you should return to the calling page? On Delevoper Community another user reported the same issue. (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1231866/cannot-debug-classic-asp-since-visual-studio-2019.html)

Comment: I'm on 16.7.7 without any problems, with several side includes. However, one difference is that I use include virtual, not include file. Maybe that's the issue? e.g. <!-- #include virtual="/myfolder/pathtomyfile.asp" -->

Comment: I tried include virtual, same error with 16.8.1.

Comment: Could you create a sample stripped down sample app which doesn't work for you and upload it somewhere and I'll try it locally? By the way, the way I debug is to attach VS2019 to the w3p.exe process, selecting "script" type for the language, rather than using a stop command... just trying to figure out some differences in our setup/process.

Comment: You can simply copy/paste the two small files (default.asp + include.asp) I wrote in the main topic. It's the simplest possible situation. To see the bug you should STEP INTO f1() (in include.asp) and try to STEP OUTSIDE (thus returning to default.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 03/03/2021**

A fix for this bug is available in Visual Studio 2019 16.9.

**UPDATE 28/12/2019**

Microsoft fixed this. Hopefully an update to Visual Studio will be available soon (details [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1231866/cannot-debug-classic-asp-since-visual-studio-2019.html)).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

After some research, it seems that this behaviour is due to a bug in Visual Studio.
I installed some different versions and this is what I found:

- v. 16.0.19: bug is not present
- v. 16.5.5: bug is not present
- v. 16.6.5: bug is not present
- v. 16.7.0: first version with bug
- v. 16.7.6: bug still present
- v. 16.8 preview 5: bug still present

I filed a bug on Microsoft Developer Community (details [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1231866/cannot-debug-classic-asp-since-visual-studio-2019.html)).

Meanwhile I installed v.16.7.6 and v.16.6.5 side by side (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio-versions-side-by-side?view=vs-2019), section "Install minor Visual Studio versions side-by-side").